# Automatic parsing from str to my enum/struct?

Tags: rust

Is it possible to tell Rust to convert `str` automatically into my type, which implements [`FromStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.FromStr.html)? I'm doing this:

```rust
use std::str::{self, FromStr};
struct Foo {}
impl FromStr for Foo {
    type Err = ParseIntError;
    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
        Ok(Foo {})
    }
}
fn x(foo : Foo) {}
fn main() {
    x("Hello, world!"); // the error is here!
}
```

I was expecting `FromStr` to help me make this conversion automatic. It seems that I still have to do this:

```
fn main() {
  x("Hello, world!".parse().unwrap());
}
```

If so, what's the point of `FromStr`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to tell Rust to convert str automatically into my type

No, that's not the sort of things Rust promotes / does / allows, even less so for faillible conversions. Rust intentionally has rather few implicit conversions, and even less so ones which run user-provided code.

> If so, what's the point of `FromStr`?

That packages can use `FromStr` as bounds in order to convert from strings to unknown types e.g. structopt can parse command-line parameters to arbitrarily complex structs.

For libraries, it also provides users with a relatively easy to discover interface e.g. the user can just check the list of traits, see that there's a `FromStr` (or a `TryFrom<&str>` these days) and know that they can use that to parse.